# Matching value of 1 dictionary with key of another dictionary using Python

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I have 2 dictionaries. Is it possible to loop  DictA's key with DictB's values, and if DictB's value has a match, it would return DictB's key.
​
Is it possible to be done?  
Please give me some advice/tips. What am I doing wrong? Thank you.

Example:

```
A: {'WNT3A': '1732', 'RG59L': ' ', 'SCZD9': ' ', 'CD241': '6005', 'C2': '', 'RH': ' '}

B: {'': [''], '6005': ['RH50A', ' CD241', ' SLC42A1'], '603': [''], '6000': [''], '8787': ['PERRS', ' RGS9L', ' MGC26458'], '41': ['ACCN2', ' BNaC2', ' hBNaC2'], '8490': [''], '9628': [''], '5999': ['SCZD9']}
```

Result :

```
new_A: {'WNT3A': '1732', 'RG59L': ' ', 'SCZD9': '5999 ', 'CD241': '6005', 'C2': '', 'RH': ' '}​
```

So far, I've coded this but it only seems to return me a dictionary that is whole or a dictionary containing only dictionary B.

```
new_a = {}
for key in ref_dict:
for value in (map(lambda x: x.strip(), ref_dict[key][0])):
    if(not fill_dict.has_key(key)):
        continue
    elif(ref_dict[value] != fill_dict[key]):
        new_a[value] = (ref_dict[key], fill_dict[key])
print new_a
```

Result:

```
{'WNT3A': '1732', 'RG59L': '', 'SCZD9': '', 'CD241': '6005', 'C2': '', 'RH': ''}
```

Another code I've tried is :

```
new_dict = {}
for k, v in fill_dict.iteritems():
    vals = []
    if isinstance(v, list):
       for i in v:
            vals.append(ref_dict.get(i))
    else:
    vals.append(ref_dict.get(v))
    if not vals:
        continue
    new_dict[k] = vals
print new_dict
```

Result:

```
{'WNT3A': [None], 'RG59L': [['']], 'SCZD9': [['']], 'CD241': [['RH50A', ' CD241', ' SLC42A1']], 'C2': [['']], 'RH': [['']]}
```

Comment: Do you want to just change dictionary A's values, or do you want to return an entirely new and independent dictionary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a dict-comprehension with [`next()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next) for this:

```
>>> {k: next((k1 for k1, v1 in B.items() if k in v1), v)  for k, v in A.items()}
{'WNT3A': '1732', 'RG59L': ' ', 'SCZD9': '5999', 'CD241': '6005', 'C2': '', 'RH': ' '}
```

Here I've used `next(<gen exp>, v)`, if the generator expression returned an empty iterator(i.e if none of the B's values contains the key `k`) then simply use the value `v` from `A`, otherwise use the key returned from the generator expression.

The above code can also be written as:

```
d = {}
for k, v in A.items():
    for k1, v1 in B.items():
        if k in v1:
            d[k] = k1
            break
    else:
        #this will be executed if no value in `B` contains `k`
        d[k] = v
```

Comment: YESS, this did the trick. Thank you so much. If you don't mind, could you explain the codes to me...because at the moment, im not sure how the code works

Answer (score 0):

This will update dictionary `a` with the values you want:

```
for key_a in a:
    for key_b, value_b in b.iteritems():
        for item in value_b:
            if item == key_a:
                a[key_a] = key_b
```

If you need a whole new `dict`, then just make a copy of `a` and update that one.